# Failed to create Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a new Google Cloud Function from the Google Cloud Console but the function fails to start with timeout error. I have already 3 cloud functions that are running.

When I am trying to create the same function from the Google Cloud shell,

```
gcloud functions deploy user_upload --runtime python37 --trigger-resource augmenta-user-uploads --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

it fails again with this message

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Failed to upload the function source code to signed url: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-204cf3ba-be49-4143-960f-fb427a786fca/b4d05dc0-07e2-4924-8dfa-26092ac05f76.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-799336262900@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1541158967&Signature=VVi0GQc1FKPbdyKC41hu1C%2FMLouyntkC%2FegRgMBRK17jSkx6iNVpH1QoBWJAl81hlrzw%2Bw4%2FTfaMowkFkfHO0e4%2FRd1UChcv3b%2BpIIqDw8hgk91r9jiS1cCMGaJc53pUaRMUKRT3CPUO%2BSQ6GLU6a1g%2Fp%2BJclSfOQOaoqsQAtThF9RZ%2BBlLdeBrXRtvxa0Odx1o5Ze0g6jsdiMCfaxojmKUy0prOEjZcJwjLfMwlwa85kugYjfGRfcjIEhJ3oENGFX2MsT%2B5hlWgA5TwyLZHplQL1jfHsqj6LHc3MLRhDMx4%2FvHPVfmhxEwXukD%2BDbHH6JIzW8buEegYHk6YKc8bAw%3D%3D.
>
> Status: [400:EntityTooLargeYour proposed upload is larger than the maximum object size specified in your Policy Document.Content-length exceeds upper bound on range]

I cannot understand what is the meaning of this message.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently a reported issue affecting Cloud Functions deployment. It's reported in the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-functions/18003).

Answer (score 3):

> When using the command-line tool, Cloud Functions packages and uploads the contents of your function's directory to a Cloud Storage bucket for you and automatically excludes unnecessary files via the .gcloudignore file.
>
> Cloud Functions can accept source code directly, or you can store your code in your own Cloud Storage bucket with the optional --stage-bucket parameter. For more information on specifying your own storage bucket for deployment, see the Cloud SDK documentation.

1. Make sure you don't have any wanted files in the directory where your source code is.
2. I don't know whats the limit for the transient bucket. If your source code is really huge, use --stage-bucket parameter with gcloud

Note: Especially if you are using some CI tools make sure you don't have any unwanted files.

Reference: [cloud functions doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem)